# Linux calendar that synchronizes with outlook

Tags: sync, thunderbird, calendar

I am using a windows phone, however my desktop OS is Ubuntu. I would find it really neat to synchronize a calendar on my phone with a calendar on my desktop computer. However, on the WP there is only the outlook calendar. I found out how I can download the stuff from outlook into the Thunderbird Lightning calendar. However, I cannot add an event in Lightning which is then uploaded to the outlook calendar.
Is there any calendar tool for Linux which interacts well with the online outlook calendar in both directions?

Comment: I am syncing outlook calendar, Iphone calendar and Thunderbird, by using google calendar.  I truly don't really want to use google, but it is at least a platform that can handle this.  The current google to outlook connector (free) is readonly - there is a business account in google which enables a read-write calendar connector.

Comment: "Maybe google calendar does this...but I don't want to use google" where also exactly my thoughts 5 seconds ago. Thanks for your answer! Maybe I will switch to google, too.

Comment: You can sync outlook to any caldav service provider like [fruux](http://fruux.com) & then sync fruux with Ubuntu(evolution-data-server) using evolution(GUI).

Answer (score 1):

For exactly the same scenario I'm currently using [mailbox.org](https://mailbox.org) which offers the total package starting from 2.5€/month: E-mails with [easy PGP integration](http://www.open-xchange.com/announcements/19), calendars, contacts, tasks, word processing, and file sharing. It's actually a very nice alternative for something like Dropbox or Google Docs.

Windows Phone sync of emails, calendars, contacts and tasks works. I'm using their ActiveSync endpoint for that, but they provide (and actually prefer) the open standards as well. The company speaks openly about its values and as far as I can tell it actually lives them. Privacy is central, it exceeds the high german standards.

The solution @KhurshidAlam proposed in his [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556697/linux-calendar-that-synchronizes-with-outlook#comment764721_556697) (which he could perfectly turn into an answer) is also excellent because it proposes using a very Open Source-friendly web service called [fruux](https://fruux.com/opensource/).

> We are behind sabre/dav, which is the most popular open source implementation of the WebDAV, CardDAV and CalDAV standards. Besides us, developers and companies around the globe use our sabre/dav technology to deliver sync functionality to millions of users.

It is also located in Germany, so it has high privacy standards to comply to. I'm going to try it out as well.

Both companies also understood the challenge that Open Source software is facing right now and that's offering good user experiences comparable to those of the popular corporates.